# How to deal with PHPDoc blocks and print width PHPCS/PHPMD rules?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpcs

I'm developing a Laravel application, and I use PHPCS, PHPMD and Prettier.

I have a `Facade` to deal with the invitation system of the app, and the PHPDoc (at the time of writing) looks like this:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @method  array  getValidationRules()  Return the validation rules.
 * @method  \App\Model\Invite  check(string $code)   Return the invite if it exists and is valid.
 * @method  \App\Model\Invite  claim(\App\Model\Invite $invite, \App\Model\User $claimerUser)  Claim the invite.
 * @method  \App\Model\Invite|null  find(string $inviteCode)  Find the invitation if it exists.
 * ...
 */
```

I'd prefer align vertically the PHPDoc items, but the PHPCS/PHPMD complains about the print width (that is 120 characters).

Is better put the documentation in a new line and break the lines whenever the line hits 120 chars our ignore the warning?

How you are dealing with this?